# Changing the value of a variable to what it might already be

Tags: javascript, variables

If I want to give a variable a value that it has a decent chance of already having, should I check whether it does and avoid unnecessary overwriting, or should I just do it and avoid the check? So (using JavaScript here), which option is less work for the processor:

```
foo = "foo"; //foo might already be set to "foo"
```

or

```
if(foo != "foo") {
    foo = "foo";
}
```

Two things to note here: first, while I'm working in JavaScript at the moment, I'd be interested in answers for other languages if they're different; and second, I will most probably be working with strings that are a lot longer than "foo".

Comment: What are you trying to do? I think we need some more context, it probably depends on the situation...

Comment: You always want foo to equal 'foo'?  Or do you want to set it to 'foo' if and only if foo is undefined?

Comment: Set it and forget it. This level of micro-optimization is __NUTS__.

Comment: @danronmoon I want to set it to "foo" if it's not equal to "foo" yet.

Comment: @Bluefire: Setting a variable is much faster than comparing strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple assignment is always going to be less costly than a condition check. That being said, this is so micro that it really does not matter.

In the case of something a little more complicated like if you only wanted to assign something to `foo` if it didn't already have a value, you could use the logical or (`||`) to do that:

```
var foo;
// ... some code that may initialize foo ...
foo = foo || 'someDefault';
```

Beware that this will also default `foo` if it has any "falsey" value: `0`, empty string, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or `false`. If those values are acceptable then you'd want to use `typeof` with a tertiary statement instead:

```
var foo;
// ... some code that may initialize foo ...
foo = typeof foo === 'undefined' ? 'someDefault' || foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to set a variable to something it might already be set to.

```
foo = "foo";
```