# Is it better to call if statement or constantly reassign value? (javascript or any language)

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the value of a variable to what it might already be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570189/changing-the-value-of-a-variable-to-what-it-might-already-be)

Which is better:

```
if(value != 1){
   value = 1
}
```

or

```
value = 1
```

(This is for a function that is in an animation loop, so its constantly being called, don't know if this is important or not, but thought that I should include that info...)

Comment: I hope you realize that "better" is not always objective. Anyway, the second version is better.

Comment: In terms of performance, it probably won't matter. IMO just setting `value = 1` looks cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the info! sorry for not realizing the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is remarkably similar to a story on [Computer Stupidities](http://www.rinkworks.com/stupid/cs_programming.shtml):

> I ran across this gem while debugging someone else's old code once:
>
> ```
> if (value == 0)
>    return value;
> else
>    return 0;
> ```

In your code, regardless of the original value of `value`, it will always be `1` by the end. So just set it that way.

Comment: perfect! thanks For the help, and I'm sorry for not noticing the duplicate :(